# cannot destruct the style object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to deconstruct the style object but it gives me error on the line `const { errorTextStyle } = myStyle;` saying: `Unexpected token (8:8)"`.
Below is the whole code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, Dimensions, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  /////////////////////
  state = {email: '', password: '', error: ''};
  const { errorTextStyle } = myStyle;
  /////////////////////    methods
  onButtonPress(){
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
    catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
      catch(() => {
        this.setState({error: 'Authentication Failed.'});
      });
    });
  }
  //////////////////////   render
  render(){
    return(
      <Card>

        <CardSection >
          <Input
            placeholder="Type here :)"
            onChangeText={ email => this.setState({ email }) }
            value={ this.state.email }
            label={ 'Email: ' }
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </CardSection >

        <CardSection >
          <Input
            placeholder="Type here :)"
            onChangeText={ password => this.setState({password}) }
            value={this.state.password}
            label={'Password: '}
            autoCorrect={false}
            secureTextEntry
          />
        </CardSection >
        <Text style={ errorTextStyle }>
          {this.state.error}
        </Text>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Login :)
          </Button>
        </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
  }
}


const myStyle = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: You're typing in the context of the `class`, which doesn't allow expressions. What are you trying to accomplish? Did you want that inside the `constructor`?

Comment: put that line, the one with `const { .. } = style` above your class definition.. while you're at it, put the style object at the top

Comment: but while i'm having a functional component i put it insude the function, why that works but here we should put it outside of class? please write it as an answer, thanks

Comment: by the way, i did pout it poutside of class, now it says: `cannot read property `errorTextStyle` od undifined`

Comment: You're going to want to destructure in the method you are looking to use the  variable. In this case you are using it in your `render()` method so you should destructure it above your return statement inside the `render() `method of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable is being used inside `render`, move that code inside that method. You can only declare methods and [fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) inside the `class` declaration, expressions must go inside a method. `state = ...` is working for you because that's a field declaration. Try the following:

```
render(){
  const { errorTextStyle } = myStyle;
  ...
}
```